# Spring+Hibernate configuration, null SessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception, spring-annotations, sessionfactory

I've been searching extensively for hours, seeing different scenarios with different approaches for a specific/common problem, but having no luck to solve a very simple Null SessionFactory. Here are my classes, I made it as short as possible so while I'm trying to cut down the codes I'm hoping to locate the problem. Still no luck.

The Service Class

```
public class Service {

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Transactional
  public void doSomething() {

     Student stud = new Student();

     stud.setName("Student");
     stud.setAge(23);
     stud.setSchool("School");

     System.out.println(sessionFactory);

     sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(stud);
   }
}
```

My Entity Class (POJO)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student extends Person {

  @Column(name = "school")
  private String school;

  public Student() {
  }

  public Student(String school) {
     this.school = school;
  }

  public String getSchool() {
    return school;
  }

  public void setSchool(String school) {
    this.school = school;
  }
}
```

The configuration file (applicationContext.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:properties/database.properties"
    ignore-unresolvable="false" />

<context:component-scan base-package="edu.service"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>edu.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And the main class

```
public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/config/applicationContext.xml");

      Service service = new Service();
      service.doSomething();

      ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).registerShutdownHook();
      ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
  } 
}
```

I really dont get why do I have a null SessionFactory, I tried to made it as short as possible, removed some part of the applications(DAOs,Services,Annotations), still no luck.
Any help please. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

First annotate or configure the service in xml.
Then get it from the context like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/config/applicationContext.xml");

    Service service = (Service) context.getBean("service");
    service.doSomething();

    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).registerShutdownHook();
    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That's the first step, but it seems there's another problem : for the `@Transactional` annotation to work, the service must implement an interface and be used through this interface.

Comment: what silly mistake on my part, I was really focused on studying the DAO/Service design pattern, I lost my attention to these kind of details >.< , It worked, thank you so much.. !!

Comment: @Jeff Happy to help. It is so trivial that it doesn't deserve a quote per say. But still here it is: "The greatest difficulties lie where we are not looking for them." - Johann Wolfgang von Goethe

Comment: @SergeBallesta actually there is(are), Im working on a DAO/Service pattern(this code is part of it) but I did not included it in here as it might cause irrelevance, so I tried so make my code SSCE(just following some general programming forum rules), I might just create another topic for it.

Comment: @Atul Thank you for the quote!, I'll take note of it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `new Service()` so the object you've created is not managed by Spring. You never called `setSessionFactory()` and so `SessionFactory` is of course null, hence an NPE when you try to reference it.

You probably want to be getting an `Service` managed by the Spring container which means you need to inject it somehow.
So try injecting the bean `Service` and then call `service.doSomething();`

Comment: thank you. I was not paying too much attention on the simple details, I was focused on designing patterns. >.< :)

Comment: I wish I can accept all answers, but I can only click one >.<, I'm just new to S.O.